# Error finding Win32 VM packProblem during build IA Project through InstallAnywhereAntTask

Tags: java, installanywhere

I have added new VM to bundled with my installer in InstallAnywhere_2011_Enterprise_SP4/resource/installer_vms/SunJRE170Win64.vm

And during build the project through I am getting below error.

Adding other errors: Error finding Win32 VM pack. "SunJRE170Win64.vm" Build using SunJRE160_01iWin32.vm (Sun JRE 1.6.0_01 i18n Win32).

Adding other errors: Error finding Linux VM pack. "SunJRE170_Linux64.vm" Build using SUN_160_B23_LINUX_64Bit.vm (Sun_JRE_160_B23_Linux64Bit).

And strange thing is that if we build using IA Project from UI its works fine and i got bundled jre of 1.7 under Program Files\ but when we build using

Ant classname="com.zerog.ia.integration.ant.InstallAnywhereAntTask" it gives me 1.6 as a bundled and its goes to Program Fiels(x86)\

Any thoughts as want to bundled jre of SunJRE170Win64.vm?

Are there any steps that i am missing?

LOGS

in build log i am getting below log

```
<InstallResources/>
 <OtherErrors>
 <Build Error type="Non-Fatal Error" description="Error finding Win32 VM pack. &quot;SunJRE170Win64.vm&quot; Build using SunJRE160_01iWin32.vm (Sun JRE 1.6.0_01 i18n Win32)."/>
 <Build Error type="Non-Fatal Error" description="Error finding Linux VM pack. &quot;SunJRE170_Linux64.vm&quot; Build using SUN_160_B23_LINUX_64Bit.vm (Sun_JRE_160_B23_Linux64Bit)."/>
 <Build Error type="Non-Fatal Error" description="Error finding Win32 VM pack. &quot;SunJRE170Win64.vm&quot; Build using SunJRE160_01iWin32.vm (Sun JRE 1.6.0_01 i18n Win32)."/>
 </OtherErrors>
 <Installers status="SUCCESS">
 <Platforms>
 <LinuxVM output="Linux" status="SUCCESS"></LinuxVM>
 <Win32VM output="Windows" status="SUCCESS"></Win32VM>
 </Platforms>
 </Installers>
```

Regards,
 Mohasin

Answer (score 0):

Could this be explained by path not being set in the way you invoke non-UI builds? I see this when setting up hudson-IA nodes, and got around problems like that by having Hudson call a Batch file, and the batch file sets up path first thing, as well as the variables USERPROFILE, IA_PROJECT_DIR and anything else your IA builds may rely on in env table.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem. After lot of investigation, this is what worked for me.

Go to  BUILD tab->Build Target->Add Build Target.Check boxes for  with VM and without VM. Also, select the radio buttons suitable for your project. I selected the default settings.

Here is the screenshot below of the settings which I did:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by copying my "Openjdk180_222.vm" to "C:\Program Files\installanywhere\v20.0\resource\installer_vms"